# Why can I not delete an accepted answer that would shame both the OP and me?

Tags: discussion

I tried to delete [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/meaning-of-make-it-that-in-the-sentence/57791#57791) accepted  answer but I couldn't. Is there any reasonable explanation?

Anyway I could delete its content but I cannot figure out why the answer once accepted cannot be deleted. It's really frustrating!

EDIT:

I think I didn't make my point clear enough. That's not my answer that bothers me (many people can make mistakes) but the act of the acceptance of a wrong answer. On the contrary, I would have liked my answer to remain as it was for future references. But since the OP refused to change the selection (I asked them twice to do it) they left me no choice but to delete the whole answer so as to leave them without an accepted answer. Of course I couldn't. I don't want to gain undeserved reputation points, it's embarrassing!

Comment: Evidently, the system lets moderators delete accepted answers. Your answer is now deleted. As a side note, there's a lesson here for OPs: [Don't accept an answer too quickly](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307).

Comment: Much obliged for your assistance @J.R.!